# Sort List<Object> taking date where the date is of type string

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, comparator

I have a list of object where the data is as follows:

```
public class User {
    public String name;
    public String date;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

- Xyz 11-10-2012
- Abc 11-10-2012
- Pqr 20-04-2012
- Ijk 24-08-2012
- Mno 22-05-2014

How do i sort the data i.e names according to the dates which comes as String. I need it to be sorted by year then month and then date.
I have tried using the below code but

```java
List<User> list = The list where i get my data
List<User> listTemp = list.stream()
                          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getDate))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The output comes as

- 8/24/2012
- 5/22/14
- 4/20/12
- 10/11/12
- 10/11/12

P.S. I can't change the type of `String` to `Date`.

Comment: So what delimiter is used in your `date` strings `-` or `/` ?

Comment: Thats probably one of the issue since i got the data with - from my excel sheet and i get / in my list object

Comment: Check my answer in a separate post. It should help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this method:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
List<User> listTemp = list .stream()
            .sorted((u1, u2) -> LocalDate.parse(u1.getDate(), formatter).compareTo(LocalDate.parse(u2.getDate(), formatter)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Doesn't this counts as changing type of ``String`` to ``Date`` ?

Comment: Not modifying `User` object in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Usually in this case it's better to convert `String` to a `Date`, but anyway here's my solution without converting:

```
List<User> listTemp = list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(u -> {
                String[] s = u.getDate().split("-");
                return s[2] + s[1] + s[0];
            }))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

P.S Obviously I do not recommend using this in real projects

Answer (score 2):

First of all you don't need the `String`-`Date` conversion here. What you need is a custom comparator able to deal with your custom format:

This is an example of working comparator. Pay attention to `Comparator.comapring` and `.thenComparing` methods. They allow you to perform consecutive comparison.

Assuming your format is `mm/dd/yyyy` the following snipped will do the trick. It will compare the `yyyy` part first, then `mm` and `dd`:

```
final String delimiter = "/";
list.stream()
    .sorted((user1, user2) -> {
        String[] date1 = user1.getDate().split(delimiter);
        String[] date2 = user2.getDate().split(delimiter);
        return Comparator.comparing((String[] arr) -> arr[2])
                         .thenComparing(arr -> arr[0])
                         .thenComparing(arr -> arr[1])
                         .compare(date1, date2);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A bit less verbose solution:

```
Function<User, String[]> splitDate = u -> u.getDate().split("/");
list.stream()
    .sorted((u1, u2) -> Comparator.comparing((String[] arr) -> arr[2])
                                  .thenComparing(arr -> arr[0])
                                  .thenComparing(arr -> arr[1])
                                  .compare(splitDate.apply(u1), splitDate.apply(u2)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

#### Update

Here's a much cleaner approach:

```java
list.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                u -> u.getDate().split(delimiter),
                Comparator.comparing((String[] arr) -> arr[2])
                           .thenComparing(arr -> arr[0])
                           .thenComparing(arr -> arr[1])))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the Comparable interface in your User class and then override the compareTo() method so that you are sorting the dates in whatever order you need. The compareTo() returns an int value, either -1 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code does not work is because currently you are comparing strings. The string comparator is not meant to compare dates, I expect to sort alphabetically or something along this line.

I am not sure why you say that you cannot parse the string to date and use the comparator of the date, it would make your life much easier. It may need some string formatting before you do that, but you will have to do string manipulation either way.

If you definitely cannot parse the strings to dates you will need to extract the date parts of the string either by string manipulation or by regex. Then you will need to convert them to numbers. You then have to implement comparator in your class and use the numbers that you have generated to make the sorting work as you wish in the comparator.

Overall I would try to find a way to convert the strings to dates, it seems like a much cleaner solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working code below:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    User2 u1 = new User2("User1","08-11-2018");
    User2 u2 = new User2("User2","09-11-2018");
    List<User2> userList = new ArrayList<User2>();
    userList.add(u2);
    userList.add(u1);
    List<User2> listTemp = userList .stream()
                .sorted((x, y) -> LocalDate.parse(x.getDate(), formatter).compareTo(LocalDate.parse(y.getDate(), formatter)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    listTemp.forEach(user -> {
        System.out.println(user);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<User> user = list.stream().
                        sorted(comparing(User::getName).
                              thenComparing(User::getName)).
                                 collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above code should help. I have used the following sample data

Abc 03-24-2011

Abc 03-19-2011

Abc 03-21-2011

This will give you a clear picture of how the sorting is done.

Name -> Year ->Month -> Date

*For your information* if **streams** are being used,modification done on the stream does not affect your original data source.Hence all the above solution changes only the **stream** not your **User** object.